# HTTP: an Internet standards track protocol?

Tags: http

I'm reading the RFC 2616 about HTTP 1.1 and I'm just stuck with the first sentence:

> This document specifies an Internet standards track protocol for the Internet community [...]

In what way HTTP is a "track protocol"? What does it mean? Isn't HTTP a protocol to exchange hyper-text (as the name says)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments#.22Standards_Track.22

Comment: also, FWIW, you should read RFC 723x. See https://www.mnot.net/blog/2014/06/07/rfc2616_is_dead

Answer (score 0):

The same introduction is mentionned in (all) The Internet protocol RFCs,

see for example RFC 1831.

"This document specifies an Internet standards track protocol for the
   Internet community, and requests discussion and suggestions for
   improvements.  Please refer to the current edition of the "Internet
   Official Protocol Standards" (STD 1) for the standardization state
   and status of this protocol.  Distribution of this memo is unlimited."

OR RFC 5531 :

This document specifies an Internet standards track protocol for the
   Internet community, and requests discussion and suggestions for
   improvements.  Please refer to the current edition of the "Internet
   Official Protocol Standards" (STD 1) for the standardization state
   and status of this protocol.  Distribution of this memo is unlimited.

The word **Track** here, means, the protocol evolutions and a roadmap of the current protocol.

By the way the schema bellow is a simplified internet protocol standardization process :

[image: simplified internet protocol standardization process]